# Can't build after updating to Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, annotations, apt, android-databinding, android-studio-2.3

Two warnings show up when I try to build my project:

> Warning:Using incompatible plugins for the annotation processing: android-apt. This may result in an unexpected behavior.

and also at the end of all the binding errors:

> Warning:The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[android.databinding.artifactType, android.databinding.printEncodedErrors, android.databinding.minApi, android.databinding.isTestVariant, android.databinding.enableDebugLogs, android.databinding.sdkDir, android.databinding.bindingBuildFolder, android.databinding.enableForTests, android.databinding.modulePackage, android.databinding.generationalFileOutDir, android.databinding.xmlOutDir]'

I tried to enable annotation processors and removed all apt reference and changed this:

> apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

to this:

> annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

but it didn't work.

Comment: I figured out that the problem was that Realm was using apt inside its plugin, so I had to update it

Comment: did you have to update to the newest version?

Comment: Yes, I had to update Realm to 3.0 so it works with annotationProcessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can down version of tools build gradle from `2.3.0` to `2.2.3` to avoid warning like that

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just replace `apt` with `annotationProcessor` in your build.gradle file.
And remove apt plugins wherever you see them.

Answer (score 0):

Android apt is no longer supported in Android studio 2.3

see https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issues/73/no-longer-compatible-with-gradle-at-v230

Answer (score 0):

after i update. i also have this kind of situation. Remove any apt like `"com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8"` from your dependencies classpath

but before that.. please invalidate cache/restart AS and clean gradle.

then

```
dependencies {
     classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
}
```

then

```
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

then

```
compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1",
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1"
```

the lastly..put this in last app module

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0"
    }
}
```